# the minimum and maximum values of the determinant of order $3\times3$ matrix with entries $\{0,1,2,3\}$

Tags: matrices, optimization, determinant

The minimum and maximum values of the determinant of order $3\times3$ matrix with entries $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: So each entry has to belong to $\{0,1,2,3\}$?

Comment: The tag police will come knocking at your door.

Comment: @vehkat What is you best so far? Have you done better than $\pm27$?

Comment: This is a very fine problem. But the "Oberlehrers" (because they don't see the solution right away) will kill it with some trumped up charges.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Aside from the tag-wiki, also the fact that (maximization) and (minimization) are [synonyms of this tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/optimization/synonyms) is a hint that this tag should be used for the type of questions which ask how to find minimum/maximum of some expression/function.

Answer (score 7):

Brute force enumeration gives a maximum of $54$ (and hence a minimum of $-54$ since $\det (-A) = - \det A$ for $n$ odd).

A maximising matrix would be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 & 3 \\
3 & 0 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

In Python:

```
import numpy
import itertools

N = 3
cols = list(itertools.product(range(0, N+1), repeat=N))
mats = itertools.product(cols, cols, cols)
sup = 0
sup_p = None
for p in mats:
    d = numpy.linalg.det(p)
    if d > sup:
        sup = d
        sup_p = p

print sup
print sup_p
```

**Note**:

A slight improvement would notice that the problem can be written
as $\max \{ \det A \,|\,  [A]_{ij} \in \{0,1,2,3\} \}$ and since the cost is
affine in each matrix element, the maximiser must have extreme values
for all entries. Hence the problem is equivalent to 
$\max \{ \det A \,|\, [A]_{ij} \in \{0,3\} \}$.

Since the problem is also equivalent to 
$\max \{ |\det A| \,|\, [A]_{ij} \in \{0,3\} \}$, the order of rows (or columns)
doesn't matter and so we can choose the first row from
$\{(0,0,0), (3,0,0), (3,3,0), (3,3,3) \}$. This reduces the search space.

Since $(0,0,0)$  (or repeating a row) will result in a zero determinant,
the search space can be reduced further to at most
$3 \cdot \binom{7}{2} = 63$ possibilities, which is a little better
than the original $4^9 = 262,144$.

And finally, although irrelevant to the problem, we note that
this solves the problem $\max \{ |\det A| \,|\, [A]_{ij} \in [0,3] \}$,
the maximum volume of a box whose sides have $l_1$ length no greater than $3$.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: I added a maximiser.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Ensure that what is 27? Just compute the determinant of the matrix above to get 54.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are getting at. I have a method above (brute force) and have also outlined other approaches that reduce the number of checks significantly. If you row reduce the above matrix (or an appropriate permutation of its rows) you get a triangular matrix with $3,3,6$ on the diagonal which has determinant 54.

Answer (score 2):

From Hadamard's determinant bound one can deduce that the absolute value of the determinant is at most $54$.  This is done as follows.  Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix whose elements lie in the interval $[0,a]$, for some positive number $a$.  Then
$$
\det M=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^n\det\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline 0 & & &\\ 0 & & \frac{2}{a}M & \\ 0 & & &\end{array}\right]=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^n\det\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline -1 & & &\\ -1 & & \frac{2}{a}M-J & \\ -1 & & &\end{array}\right],
$$
where $J$ is the all-ones matrix.  The matrix in the final expression is an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix whose elements lie in the interval $[-1,1]$.  Its rows are therefore vectors of length at most $\sqrt{n+1}$, and its determinant is at most $(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}$.  Hence
$$
\lvert\det M\rvert\le\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^n(n+1)^{(n+1)/2}.
$$
Applying this to the case $n=3$, $a=3$, we find that $\lvert\det M\rvert\le54$.

To see whether the bound can actually be attained, note first that the maximum and minimum values of $\det M$ differ only in sign since swapping two rows or two columns of $M$ negates its determinant.  As pointed out by copper.hat, there is no need ever to use elements other than $0$ and $3$.  Hence in the matrix in the final expression above, there is no need to use elements other than $-1$ and $1$.  Equality in Hadamard's bound is attained only by matrices with pairwise orthogonal rows, that is, by Hadamard matrices.

That a $4\times4$ Hadamard matrix exists is known due to a construction of Sylvester:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\otimes\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is such a matrix.  Negating row $2$, $3$, and $4$, adding $J$ to the $3\times3$ submatrix in the lower right corner, and multiplying by $\frac{3}{2}$ gives the matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 3 & 3\\ 3 & 3 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which has determiant $-54$.  Swapping two rows gives a matrix with determinant $54$.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know anything about Hadamard's inequality...
But I have a better technique.
Here the smallest element is $0$ and the largest element is $3$
So, the determinant will be max when $0$ is the diagonal element and $3$ is the non-diagonal element, meaning that the answer is $54$.